# How to reference Stage in controller class?

Tags: java, javafx, fullscreen

> Main.class

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Main.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

> MainController.class

```
    public class MainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private MediaView mv;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private Media me;

    @FXML Slider volumeSlider;

    DoubleProperty width;
    DoubleProperty height;

    Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String path = new File("src/media/my.mp4").getAbsolutePath();
        me = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
        mp = new MediaPlayer(me);
        mv.setMediaPlayer(mp);
        //mp.setAutoPlay(true);

        stage = (Stage) mv.getScene().getWindow();  // Error occured

        width = mv.fitWidthProperty();
        height = mv.fitHeightProperty();
        width.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.sceneProperty(), "width"));
        height.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.sceneProperty(), "height"));

        volumeSlider.setValue(mp.getVolume() * 100);
        volumeSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {

            @Override
            public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.setVolume(volumeSlider.getValue() / 100);
            }
        });
    }

    public void play(ActionEvent event){
        mp.play();
        mp.setRate(1);
    }
    public void pause(ActionEvent event){
        mp.pause();
    }
    public void fast(ActionEvent event){
        mp.setRate(2);
    }
    public void slow(ActionEvent event){
        mp.setRate(.5);
    }
    public void reload(ActionEvent event){
        mp.seek(mp.getStartTime());
        mp.play();
    }
    public void start(ActionEvent event){
        mp.seek(mp.getStartTime());
        mp.stop();
    }
    public void last(ActionEvent event){
        mp.seek(mp.getTotalDuration());
        mp.stop();
    }
    public void fullScreen(ActionEvent event){

    }
}
```

> Error

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/SOONMYUN/workspace/MediaPlayer/bin/application/Main.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:17)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at application.MainController.initialize(MainController.java:44)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 17 more
```

I want to get the Stage from Main class to Controller class but it was failed.

Because I should use the setFullScreen function in Controller class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

i am answering how to pass stage object from main class to your controller class
create a function in your controller class

```
public void setStage(Stage stage){
this.stage=stage;
}
```

now call this function in your main class like this

```
 FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/application/Main.fxml"));
                Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
  ((MainController) fxmlLoader.getController()).setStage(primaryStage);
```

if you want to get the stage object without passing it from main to class to controller class you can do this way

1.Give id to your AnchorPane e.g. **fx:id="ap"** then in your Controller class

```
@FXML
AnchorPane ap;
```

2.where you want the object

```
Stage stage = (Stage) ap.getScene.getWindow();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It's working

Comment: Glad it helped. please upvote and accept the answer

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't upvote because I have not enough Reputation..

Comment: @SoonmyunJang no need to sorry buddy. happy coding

Comment: Hi.  The setStage function successfully runs, but when I try to use stage in my controller class, `stage.sizeToScene()` gives me a nullpointerexception.  I use `stage.sizeToScene()` in a separate function `authenticate(ActionEvent event)` in the same controller class.  Would I need to pass `stage` into this `authenticate(ActionEvent event)` function?  Thanks.

Comment: @RileyFitzpatrick NullPointerException means it's not initialized when you are trying to use it. make sure you've called setStage like in the answer. if it still giving you the exception you can use any of your UI element like button to access stage object. just like other way specified in the answer. let me know if you need help.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually able to fix this by creating a `new Runnable()` inside my `initialize()`.

Comment: 7 days of searching finally got a stage in the controller. but why we can't declare it as a private global variable in the FXMLDocumentController file? as local variable, it works fine

Answer (score 2):

To access stage from controller:

- Create a *setter method for stage variable* in your Controller class
- Get instance of the controller in your **Main.java class**
- Set the stage variable of controller through setter method in Main.java

  **Illustration:**

  **Step 1 :**

  ```
      public class MainCOntroller {

       private Stage primaryStage;

          public void setPrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage){
                     this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
           }
              .....
             .....      
       }
  ```

  **Step 2 and 3:** *get the instance of controller and set the stage using setter method*

  ```
    public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/application/Main.fxml"));
       Parent root = (Parent)loader.load();

       MainController controller = (MainController) loader.getController(); 

        //set stage 
         controller.setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
    } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I appreciate of you. I resolved the problem thanks to your answer!

Comment: you are welcome